# Using RAND Functions for individual cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When using any RAND functions, it requires a trigger like F9 to recalculate the value of the cells.

For example I have both A1 and B1 with =RANDBETWEEN(1,6), and hitting F9 would trigger both cells to recalculate the values. Is there a way to only trigger one cell at a time, or not?

Comment: Only if you switch off automatic recalculation (under options/formulas). You can then recalculate the individual ones by editing the cell. But then everything else in your workbook will also be manual...

Comment: You'll have to step up to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop recalculation for individual cells but you can use formula which retains their value despite recalculation.
First you must enable iterative calculations (in options, formulas tab).
Then you can enter formula like below into the `A1` cell and copy to `B1`.
Values `TRUE|FALSE` or `1|0` in the cells `A2` and `B2` control possible value changes in cells `A1` and `B1`. `TRUE` enables the cell above to change its value.
[image: RANDBETWEEN]

Comment: Thanks, this was a helpful alternative for dealing with this issue. Too bad there isn't a way to focus the recalculation trigger to one cell or even a specified range of cells.

Comment: This is only a general idea. If you have two cells only and want to use single cell e.g. `A2` as a trigger you can enter in `B1` a bit different formula `=IF(OR(NOT(A2),B1=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,6),B1)`